# Not adding correctly javascript

Tags: javascript, helper

Hello everyone so I've currently made 2 of my selection boxes for the Travel article working and I'm just doing that so I can make sure it works. What my plan is to make all the sections check boxes in each of the three articles. Then display the total cost of your trip to Las Vegas in the section that is currently in the footer.(Will be moved later to desired spot but for now its fine.) So currently the code doesn't display any errors and I'm really confused by it. What its meant to do is when a selection is selected it adds 1 to the global variable flightsel1 so then I can later check if flightsel1 & flightsel2 are selected then the code runs the function calcResult(). Which is meant to check if the totalCost is less than 300 or more than then it will run more code. What that method does is basically my way of checking if something else is selected and if it is to remove the cost so that the totalCost doesn't just keep adding. Anyways it doesn't work when it looks to me it should. So if anyone can lend a hand that would be greatly appreciated!!

```js
var flightsel1 = 0;
var flightsel2 = 0;
var totalCost = 0;
 function flight1() {
  flightsel1 = flightsel1+1;
  flightsel2 = flightsel2-100;
  calcResult(); 
 }
 function flight2() {
  flightsel2 = flightsel2+1;
  flightsel1 = flightsel1-100;
  calcResult();  
 }
 function calcResult() {
  if(flightsel1==0) {
   }
   else if(flightsel1==1){
    if(totalCost < 300){
    totalCost = totalCost + 350;
    document.getElementById("Cost").innerHTML = "Total cost : " + totalCost;
   }
   else if (totalCost > 300){
    totalCost = totalCost - 1000;
    totalCost = totalCost + 350;
    document.getElementById("Cost").innerHTML = "Total cost : " + totalCost;
   }
   }
  if(flightsel2==0) {
  }
   else if(flightsel2==1) {
    if(totalCost < 300){
    totalCost = totalCost + 450;
    document.getElementById("Cost").innerHTML = "Total cost : " + totalCost;
   }
   else if (totalCost > 300){
    totalCost = totalCost - 1000;
    totalCost = totalCost + 450
    document.getElementById("Cost").innerHTML = "Total cost : " + totalCost;
   }
   }
  if(flightsel1==1 && flightsel2==1){
   alert("You can only select 1 Flight!");
  } 
 }
 function endResult() {
  
 }
```

```css
body
{
 background-color: #808080;

}
p
{
 !-- 
}
p.travelclassheader
{
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 35px;
 font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 line-height: 150%;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px grey;
 word-spacing: 3px;
 letter-spacing: -1;
 font-variant: small-caps;
}
header
{
 text-align:center;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px grey;
 color: silver;  
 padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
 border-bottom: #808080;
 position: fixed;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #00FFF5;
 top: -10;
 height: 150px;
 left: -10;
 width: 105%;
 z-index:5;
}  
header a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align:center;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px grey;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 line-height: 100%;
 color: white;
 word-spacing: 3px;
 letter-spacing: -1;
 font-variant: small-caps;

}
hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
header a:visited
{
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align:center;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px grey;
 color: silver;  

}
article
{

}
article.travelclass
{
 text-align:center;
 color: silver;   
 padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    background-color: #393E46;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #00FFF5;
 border-top: 2px solid #00FFF5;
 height: 350px;
 float: left;
 width: 75%;
 max-width: 350px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
article.travelclass img
{ 
 float: right;
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-right: 25px;
 margin-top: -15px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
article.accommodationclass
{
 text-align:center;
 color: silver;   
 padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    background-color: #393E46;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #00FFF5;
 border-top: 2px solid #00FFF5;
 height: 350px;
 position: relative;
 top: -140px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 75%;
 max-width: 350px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
article.toursclass
{
 text-align:center;
 color: silver;   
 padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    background-color: #393E46;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #00FFF5;
 border-top: 2px solid #00FFF5;
 height: 350px;
 position: relative;
 top: -557px;
 right: -470px;
 width: 75%;
 max-width: 350px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
article.costclass
{ 
 padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    background-color: #393E46;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #00FFF5;
 border-top: 2px solid #00FFF5;
 height: 35px;
 position: relative;
 top: -580px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: white;
 font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 text-align: justify;
 left: 0px;
 width: 75%;
 max-width: 350px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
h5
{
 top: 1000px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: white;
 font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 text-align: center; 
}
footer
{
 text-align:center;
 color: silver;  
    background-color: #393E46;
 padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
 border-bottom: #808080;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 height: 25px;
 border-top: 2px solid #00FFF5;
 width: 105%;
}
```

```html
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css">
  <TITLE>Las Vegas | Home</TITLE>
  <script src="JAVASCRIPT/main.js"></script>

 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
  <HEADER>
  <style>
  header {
   background-image: url("IMAGES/banner.jpg");
  }
  </style>
   <a name="top"><H1>Las Vegas</H1></A>
  </HEADER>
  <div id="home"></div>
  <br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><hr><br><br>
  <br>
  <ARTICLE class="travelclass">
  <p class="travelclassheader">Travel</p>
  <hr>
  <p class="class2"><input type="radio" id="flight1" name=flight" value="Qantas" onClick="flight1()">Qantas $350</p>
  <p class="class2"><input type="radio" id="flight2" name=flight" value="Virgin" onClick="flight2()">Virgin $450</p>
  <p class="class2">Jetstar - $000</p>
  <hr>
  </ARTICLE>
  <br><br><br><br><br>
  <ARTICLE class="accommodationclass">
  <p class="travelclassheader">Accommodation</p>
  <hr>
  <p class="class2">Hotel 1 - $000</p>
  <p class="class2">Hotel 2 - $000</p>
  <p class="class2">Hotel 3 - $000</p>
  <hr>
  </ARTICLE>
  <br><br><br><br><br>
  <! Tours class is checkboxes for javascript/>
  <ARTICLE class="toursclass">
  <p class="travelclassheader">Tours</p>
  <hr>
  <p class="class2">Tour 1 - $000</p>
  <p class="class2">Tour 2 - $000</p>
  <p class="class2">Tour 3 - $000</p>
  <hr>
  </ARTICLE>
  <ARTICLE class="costclass">
  <p class="costtitle"><h5>Total Cost : </h5></p>
  </ARTICLE>
  <FOOTER>
   <NAV>
   <p id=test>Test lolol</p>
   <p id=Cost></p>
    All Copyright reserved 2017 &copy;<br>
   </NAV>
  </FOOTER>
 
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: If you create a [mcve] you greatly improve your chances of getting an answer. Dumping all of your existing code in the question is not recommended.

Comment: thanks for the response, im fairly new to javascript and I really need to get this function done. I dont understand the link you provided.. I could really use someone to help me get this working and simplified.

Comment: yeah...SO isn't a code writing service

Comment: could anyone help at least..?